# I am getting a CS1061 error with a RazerPages app that tells me a definition doesn't exist but it does, can someone point out to me the issue?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am working on a CRUD ASP.NET Razor Pages app that allows a user to search continents, countries, and add and remote data about them. I am getting the following error about the index model for the index page:

> Error CS1061 'IndexModel' does not contain a definition for 'SearchString' and no accessible extension method 'SearchString' accepting a first argument of type 'IndexModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var countries = from c in _context.Countries
                            select c;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
            {
                countries = countries.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(SearchString));
            }

            Countries = await countries.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Country Country = await _context.Countries.FindAsync(id);

            if (Country != null)
            {
                _context.Countries.Remove(Country);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string SearchString { get; set; }
    }
```

Can someone point out to me why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, I should've used the following using directive:

```
@using RazorCountry.Pages.Countries
```